# GNU Parallel not returning output values across remote hosts

Tags: gnu-parallel

Having problem where is appears that parallel (downloaded from `yum` via [epel](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-redhat-7-x/), not the gnu parallels site) is not returning values from processes being distributed to remote hosts and am not sure why.

The concurrent job I'm trying to run is similar to this simple [example](https://spectraldifferences.wordpress.com/2015/04/26/execute-commands-on-multiple-computers-using-gnu-parallel-setting-up-a-cluster-on-the-cheap/)...

```sh
[myuser]$  parallel -q -j 5 \
    --sshloginfile ./parallel-nodes.txt \
    echo "Number {}: Running on `hostname`" ::: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Number 9: Running on HW04.co.local
Number 3: Running on HW04.co.local
Number 5: Running on HW04.co.local
Number 8: Running on HW04.co.local
Number 2: Running on HW04.co.local
Number 6: Running on HW04.co.local
^C^C^C^C%
```

This hangs until I *ctl+c* out (ie. can only run from the calling host). When not providing an `sshloginfile`, there is no problem...

```sh
[myuser]$ parallel -q -j 5 echo "Number {}: Running on `hostname`" ::: 1 2 3 
Number 3: Running on HW04.co.local
Number 1: Running on HW04.co.local
Number 2: Running on HW04.co.local
```

- I can confirm that all of the nodes in the `--sshloginfile` have passwordless ssh enabled and can [ssh passwordless](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#sshlogin-hostgroup) between all the nodes involved.
- Can also confirm that gnu parallels is installed on all of the nodes involved.
- And that the user calling `parallel` exists on all the nodes involved
- as well as checking that all of the host FQDNs as they appear in the `sshloginfile` are named the same in the involved hosts' `.ssh/known_hosts` file.

When trying to run this and seeing it hanging, I tried examining the processes on each node that could be related to the `parallel` command...

```sh
[root@HW01 ~]# clush -ab "ps -aux | grep echo"
---------------
HW01
---------------
root     136318  0.0  0.0 294648 16468 pts/2    Sl+  15:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/clush -ab ps -aux | grep echo
root     136322  0.0  0.0 185096  4824 pts/2    S+   15:39   0:00 ssh -oForwardAgent=no -oForwardX11=no -oConnectTimeout=15 -oBatchMode=yes HW01 ps -aux | grep echo
root     136323  0.0  0.0 185096  4824 pts/2    S+   15:39   0:00 ssh -oForwardAgent=no -oForwardX11=no -oConnectTimeout=15 -oBatchMode=yes HW02 ps -aux | grep echo
root     136324  0.0  0.0 185096  4820 pts/2    S+   15:39   0:00 ssh -oForwardAgent=no -oForwardX11=no -oConnectTimeout=15 -oBatchMode=yes HW03 ps -aux | grep echo
root     136325  0.0  0.0 185096  4824 pts/2    S+   15:39   0:00 ssh -oForwardAgent=no -oForwardX11=no -oConnectTimeout=15 -oBatchMode=yes HW04 ps -aux | grep echo
root     136334  0.0  0.0 113176  1584 ?        Ss   15:39   0:00 bash -c ps -aux | grep echo
root     136351  0.0  0.0 112712   968 ?        S    15:39   0:00 grep echo
---------------
HW02
---------------
root      85835  0.0  0.0 113176  1580 ?        Ss   15:39   0:00 bash -c ps -aux | grep echo
root      85846  0.0  0.0 112708   968 ?        S    15:39   0:00 grep echo
---------------
HW03
---------------
root     120282  0.0  0.0 113176  1576 ?        Ss   15:39   0:00 bash -c ps -aux | grep echo
root     120293  0.0  0.0 112708   968 ?        S    15:39   0:00 grep echo
---------------
HW04
---------------
hph_etl  113600  1.5  0.0 157516 11944 pts/2    S+   15:39   0:00 perl /bin/parallel -q -j 5 --sshloginfile /home/me/projects/myproject/parallel-nodes.txt echo Number {}: Running on HW04.co.local ::: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
root     114154  0.0  0.0 113176  1584 ?        Ss   15:39   0:00 bash -c ps -aux | grep echo
root     114168  0.0  0.0 112712   960 ?        S    15:39   0:00 grep echo
```

So it seems as if the command is never communicated to the other nodes at all and just stays on the calling node (here HW04). Yet, checking if `firewalld` is running on any of the hosts...

```sh
[root@HW01 ~]# clush -ab systemctl status firewalld
---------------
HW01
---------------
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
---------------
HW02
---------------
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)

Jul 16 15:17:27 HW02.ucera.local systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Jul 16 15:17:28 HW02.ucera.local systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Jul 17 16:05:32 HW02.ucera.local systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Jul 17 16:05:33 HW02.ucera.local systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
---------------
HW03
---------------
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)

Jul 16 15:11:15 HW03.ucera.local systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Jul 16 15:11:16 HW03.ucera.local systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Jul 17 16:05:46 HW03.ucera.local systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Jul 17 16:05:47 HW03.ucera.local systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
---------------
HW04
---------------
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2019-07-25 15:00:33 HST; 4 days ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
  Process: 3303 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid $FIREWALLD_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3303 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 25 15:00:32 HW04.ucera.local systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Jul 25 15:00:33 HW04.ucera.local systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
clush: HW[01-04] (4): exited with exit code 3
```

shows it to be inactive on all hosts.

At this point, not sure what is going wrong. Can anyone think of any debugging suggestions or fixes?

** Also, neither of the commands listed above worked when including the `--bibtex` option in the command. Does anyone know why that would happen?

Comment: What is the output of `parallel --version` on the local and remote systems? I cannot reproduce your findings. But using backquotes in double quotes is probably not what you mean (it will always say: `Running on HW04.co.local` - because `hostname` is run before `parallel` is even started).

Comment: It does not make sense to run `--bibtex` with any other options. In newer versions `parallel` will tell you it has ignored all other options.

Comment: @OleTange "It does not make sense to run `--bibtex`" Interesting, from running the command w/out the option, there is output about citing parallels in published work. From that output, I thought that using `--bibtex` would just suppress this, but I guess not.

Comment: `--bibtex` will silence the citation notice forever. But you need to run it on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you link to, see how the backquotes are backslashed? You need to do that or else `hostname` gets executed in your shell on HW04, before it talks to other machines.

First off, I'd try this to see whether you are talking to those other machines at all:

```
parallel -j 5 \
    --sshloginfile ./parallel-nodes.txt \
    echo "Number {}: Running on \`hostname\`" ::: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Then, I'd try tracking down your passwordless ssh setup one machine at a time to make sure it's really working; from HW04 try:

```
parallel -S HW01 'echo -n {} ""; hostname' ::: 1
parallel -S HW02 'echo -n {} ""; hostname' ::: 1
parallel -S HW03 'echo -n {} ""; hostname' ::: 1
parallel -S HW04 'echo -n {} ""; hostname' ::: 1
```

(repeat for every machine in your `parallel-nodes.txt` file)

If one of those machines isn't working with ssh, you can try to debug it with:

```
PARALLEL_SSH='ssh -v' parallel -S HW03 'echo -n {} ""; hostname' ::: 1
```

Comment: The example I linked did not actually work as-is for me. Having `parallel` run `echo "Number {}: Running on \`hostname\`" ::: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` as you and the example recommend just printed "Number X: Running on `hostname`" a few times (< 10, I assume the remaining are just hanging on the remote hosts). Does it work on your machine?

Comment: It does, but only once I remove the `-q` option. Sorry for copying that from your example. (answer updated)

Comment: Running `parallel -S HW04 'echo -n {} ""; hostname' ::: 1` on host HW04 showed errors. Ie. I think the **problem was that there was no passwordless ssh from the hosts *to themselves*** (which I did not think would be a problem, but apparently is) (also added the hosts FQDN / name as appears in the `sshloginfile` to the hosts' `.ssh/known_hosts` file).

Comment: Try: `parallel -vv -S HW04 'echo -n {} ""; hostname' ::: 1` This will show exactly what GNU Parallel runs. If you can run _that_ command directly, then `parallel` should work, too.

Comment: If you want to use the local machine but without ssh'ing to the machine, you should use the special sshlogin `:` like this: `parallel -S : echo ::: foo`